# What is the meaning of using netplan?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, networkmanager, netplan

I’m running a few Ubuntu servers and recently started upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. In this context I came in contact with NetworkManager and netplan.

After sticking to ifupdown first, I finally decided to migrate to NettworkManager due to a bug in a software that I’m using (it did not recognise the machine without NetworkManager).
In this context I dont really understand the sense behind netplan. Why would anybody use netplan instead of putting the config directly into NetworkManager? Just because yaml reads better?

Comment: Similar on askubuntu `https://askubuntu.com/q/1005390/5927`.